# How to catching doubleClick events from NSOutlineView in ViewController?

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I am trying to catch doubleClick events from my NSOutlineView to be passed to my ViewController. My idea is to catch doubleClick events and to get the selected row from my OutlineView
What I did so far was subclassing the NSOutlineView in order to overwrite mouseDown

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
   super.mouseDown(with: event)
   if event.clickCount >= 2 {
      ... 
   }
}
```

That works well however I don't know how to pass this event to my ViewController. The ViewController is already implementing the NSOutlineViewDelegate protocol.

I guess that the solution is not far away but somehow I am stuck.

Comment: I want to add that I also want to select a row if only one click occurs. Then the row should be selected. On a doubleClick another event should be triggered.

Comment: Another event in addition to selecting the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Although you can set up `NSGestureRecognizer` for single click and `NSClickGestureRecognizer` for double clicks in OSX, You should probably be using the `doubleAction` property of the `NSOutlineView` directly.

Here's an example of how to set it up
[image]

This comes from a another of the [Wenderlich tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123463/nsoutlineview-macos-tutorial), and there is a good discussion on [SO already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620603/double-click-an-nstableview-row-in-cocoa)

Comment: You can use the tap gesture in Cocoa?  I didn't know that.

Comment: sorry - I missed that we're talking OSX, but you can use `NSGestureRecognizer` rather than `UIGestureRecognizer`.  Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsgesturerecognizer

Comment: @Russel, thanks for the answer. I am away from my Mac but if I have understood you correctly I need to

* Instantiate a NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: myViewController, action: handleGesture)

* Add the gestureRecognizer to my NSOutlineView

* Implement a handleGesture method in myViewController

Comment: @Russell: Aarrgh! The Ray Wenderlich Tutorials are always my first place to look. Must have missed out this one. Thanks for mentioning :-)