# MouseDown Event prevents NSCollectionView Delegate Methods

Tags: swift, macos, events, mousedown, nscollectionview

I would like to implement an action by double clicking an item within a `NSCollectionView`. When using the `mouseDown`event in the `NSCollectionViewItem` no collection view delegate method is fired anymore nor does the items property `isSelected` work:

the `mouseDown` event in the `NSCollectionViewItem.swift`:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {

    if event.clickCount > 1 {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How do I need to handle click events on `CollectionViewItems` and `CollectionView` delegate methods at the same time?

**Other than `NSTableview` or `NSOutlineView` there is no implemented `doubleAction` method for `NSCollectionView`. Which is sad.**

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catching doubleClick events from NSOutlineView in ViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989426/how-to-catching-doubleclick-events-from-nsoutlineview-in-viewcontroller)

Comment: @Willeke, no duplicate answer. Unfortunately, there is no `doubleAction` method in `NSCollectionView` integrated.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed `NSCollectionView` and `NSOutlineView` up (again). If you don't handle single clicks yourself, call `super.mouseDown(with: event)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you override `mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)`, then remember to call `super.mouseDown(with: event)` in it; otherwise, your collectionView delegate methods won't be called.

I'm answering this not to steal @Willeke solution in the comment above, but only because I don't want his comment (perfectly on point) to be missed by someone else! If Willeke wants to answer, I'll delete this.